# How to organize work with tokens in Android mobile client and OAuth2.0 entry point

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, token

My mobile application allows the user to register on the website. 
When the user is registered on the webiste, I receive token which is generated for this user and time when this token will expire. And i want to ask one question.
I have the variable which stores the expiration time (in seconds) for the token. So when I have received the token I need to calculate the expiration date for this token according to expiration time variable. **Something like this: expirationDate = currentDate + expirationTime?** And then every time, when the user opens my application, I should check the date, and if the date equals or greater than expirationDate, I need to ask user to re-authorize, and get new token?

Comment: and your problem is...?

Comment: I would like to clarify is whether my approach to work with the tokens in the above situation correct?

Comment: see AccountManager, training here: http://doc.gotomao.com/doc/android/api/training/id-auth/authenticate.html